# Remove Apply and Clear buttons from PrimeNg MultiSelect

Tags: angular, primeng, multi-select

I've been learning PrimeNg [MultiSelect](https://primeng.org/multiselect), I'm trying to figure out how I go about hiding the Clear and Apply Buttons within the MultiSelect option inside my [table](https://primeng.org/table#filter), I can't find anywhere in the docs that outline this.

My MultiSelect currently looks like this:

[image]

How can I remove the bottom buttons?

This is my current HTML structure:

```
<p-columnFilter field="serviceCode" matchMode="in" display="menu" [showMatchModes]="false" [showOperator]="false" [showAddButton]="false">
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <div class="px-3 pt-3 pb-0">
            <span class="font-bold">Service Code</span>
        </div>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="filter" let-value let-filter="filterCallback">
        <p-multiSelect [ngModel]="value" [options]="serviceCodes"
            [(ngModel)]="selectedServiceCodes" placeholder="Any"
            (onChange)="filterTableByStatusCode()" optionLabel="serviceCode">
            <ng-template let-option pTemplate="item">
                <div class="inline-block vertical-align-middle">
                    <span class="ml-1 mt-1">{{ option }}</span>
                </div>
            </ng-template>
        </p-multiSelect>
    </ng-template>
</p-columnFilter>
```

An pointers, would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have a stackblitz example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To hide the buttons within the `p-columnFilter` tag, you can achieve it by adding the following attributes:

```
[showApplyButton]="false"
[showClearButton]="false"
```

These attributes allow you to control the visibility of the apply and clear buttons associated with the `p-columnFilter` component. By setting their values to "false", the buttons will be hidden from view

Comment: I get Can't bind to 'showApplyButton' since it isn't a known property of 'p-table'.

Comment: Also tried adding that to the multiselect and same error

Comment: I apologize for the confusion in my previous response. Instead of adding the attributes to the `p-table` component, you should add them to the `p-columnFilter` component.
By doing this, the `p-columnFilter` component should function as expected. @CodeRatchet

Comment: I did figure it out earlier, but given you pointing me on the right track I'll accept your answer